# python ctypes array will not return properly

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

This does not work:

```
def CopyExportVars(self, n_export):
    export_array = (ctypes.c_double * n_export)()
    self.dll_handle.vs_copy_export_vars(ctypes.cast(export_array,  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)))
    return export_array().contents
```

I get this error (`n_export` is 3):

```
TypeError: 'c_double_Array_3' object is not callable
```

Comment: `return export_array.contents`?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski without the parens, it complains there is no attribute of 'contents'.

Comment: Geez, sorry about that, `export_array` is value, not a pointer. Since it's a `ctypes` array, you may index it to retireve values, `export_array[0]` all up to `export_array[n_export-1]`

Comment: Ok, that helps.  It's just an array.  How can I return the entire array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is pretty self-explainatory. `export_array` is not a callable object, but you try to call it in last line of function. Also, you try to use pointer-related interface ('.contents') to retrieve value from array, not pointer to it.

Simplest way to make it work would be to convert `ctypes` result array to pure Python object and return it:

```
def CopyExportVars(self, n_export):
    export_array = (ctypes.c_double * n_export)()
    self.dll_handle.vs_copy_export_vars(ctypes.cast(export_array,  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)))
    return list(export_array)
```